# Getting error in testing facebook business-sdk

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-business-sdk

I started with facebook business sdk for php. Was following this doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/business-sdk/getting-started/
installed without trouble, then tried testing as they instructed,
created src/test.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Logger\CurlLogger;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
use FacebookAds\Object\Campaign;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\CampaignFields;

$app_id = "{app-id}";
$app_secret = "{appsecret}";
$access_token = "{access-token}";
$account_id = "act_{{adaccount-id}}";

Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);

$account = new AdAccount($account_id);
$cursor = $account->getCampaigns();

// Loop over objects
foreach ($cursor as $campaign) {
  echo $campaign->{CampaignFields::NAME}.PHP_EOL;
}
```

filled in the required values. and ran the file. Getting this:

```
FacebookAds\CrashReporter : Enabled
FacebookAds\CrashReporter : Exception detected!
FacebookAds\CrashReporter : Successfully sent report
Fatal error: Uncaught FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException: Invalid OAuth access token. in C:\laragon\www\testPro\vendor\facebook\php-business-sdk\src\FacebookAds\Http\Exception\RequestException.php:174
Stack trace:
#0 C:\laragon\www\testPro\vendor\facebook\php-business-sdk\src\FacebookAds\Http\Client.php(215): FacebookAds\Http\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(FacebookAds\Http\Response))
#1 C:\laragon\www\testPro\vendor\facebook\php-business-sdk\src\FacebookAds\Http\Request.php(286): FacebookAds\Http\Client->sendRequest(Object(FacebookAds\Http\Request))
#2 C:\laragon\www\testPro\vendor\facebook\php-business-sdk\src\FacebookAds\Api.php(165): FacebookAds\Http\Request->execute()
#3 C:\laragon\www\testPro\vendor\facebook\php-business-sdk\src\FacebookAds\Api.php(214): FacebookAds\Api->executeRequest(Object(FacebookAds\Http\Request))
#4 C:\laragon\www\testPro\vendor\facebook\php-business-sdk\src\FacebookAds\ApiRequest.php(187): FacebookAds\Api->call('/act_3667840345...', 'GET', Array, Array)
#5 in C:\laragon\www\testPro\vendor\facebook\php-business-sdk\src\FacebookAds\Http\Exception\RequestException.php on line 174
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Didnt find much by searching. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is pretty explicit: "Invalid OAuth access token"
you can check the token you supplied using Facebook's token-debbuger @ https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

most probably you are missing the "ads_management" permission.